# Case function formula in Sales force

Tags: salesforce

I did use the case statement to create a character field with the correct numbering separator from a numeric field based on the currency symbol, I think I only need to evaluate two cases if it is "€" using space as separator and anything else just use the comma ","

I'm having a problem to simplify the case function formula below, right now I evaluating  "€", "$", and  "£" and I think it is unnecessary.

Thanks in advance!

```
CASE(Currency_Symbol__c, "€", IF(
Room_Size__c >= 1000000,
TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000000)) & " ",
"") &
IF(
Room_Size__c >= 1000,
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000)), 3) & " ",
"") &
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c)), 3), "$", 
IF(
Room_Size__c >= 1000000,
TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000000)) & ",",
"") &
IF(
Room_Size__c >= 1000,
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000)), 3) & ",",
"") &
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c)), 3), "£", 
IF(
Room_Size__c >= 1000000,
TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000000)) & ",",
"") &
IF(
Room_Size__c >= 1000,
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000)), 3) & ",",
"") &
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c)), 3),"0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting lost in too many `()`?

I'd start by formatting it bit better:

```
CASE(Currency_Symbol__c,
    "€",    IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000000, TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000000)) & " ", "")
            & IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000, RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000)), 3) & " ","") 
            & RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c)), 3),
    ...
)
```

So to have just € and default:

```
CASE(Currency_Symbol__c,
    "€",    IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000000, TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000000)) & " ", "")
            & IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000, RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000)), 3) & " ","") 
            & RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c)), 3),
    IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000000, TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000000)) & ",", "")
        & IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000, RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000)), 3) & ",","") 
        & RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c)), 3),
)
```

Or... now you have a CASE with just 2 branches - maybe this would look cleaner?

```
IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000000,
    TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000000)) + IF(Currency_Symbol__c = '€', ' ', ','),
    ''
) +
IF(Room_Size__c >= 1000,
    TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c / 1000)) + IF(Currency_Symbol__c = '€', ' ', ','),
    ''
) +
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(Room_Size__c)), 3)
```